# Logic Circuits Vs Transistor Power Circuits

Tags: transistors, digital-logic

I have need to invert a signal to drive fets with hard/fast rise and fall times.  I was told in another thread to use an inverter (NOT chip).  This makes perfect sense to me since logic chips are always hard ON or OFF by design.  But I've never worked with logic chips before.  All I've dealt with is 555s and transistor/fet power circuits.  Are there any 'gotchas' or special things I need to know to implement a NOT chip into a 555 output to switch a FET without any hiccups?  For that matter, are there any 'gotches' or things in general that apply to logic circuitry that someone with my background wouldn't know and might stumble on?

- Jim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use a Comparator

"Digital" NOT gates (inverters) are comparatively weak, since they are not designed to drive big loads. In the more general case, you want a circuit topology known as a comparator.

A comparator compares the input voltage to a reference and outputs one of it's maximum extents (as close to its positive or negative supply as it can get) if the input is even the slightest bit above or below the reference.

This appears to be your desired behavior.

You can easily create a comparator out of an operational amplifier (op-amp) by removing the feedback network as shown below. Without feedback the open-loop gain of the amplifier will directly apply without mitigation.

The output is therefore just the input minus the reference times a very large gain factor. The output voltage can't exceed the power supply (of course), so a practical circuit will be limited to the rails (just as your "digital" inverters are).

The upside is that the op-amp will be much stronger (faster, capable of driving larger loads). The down-side is that it will use more power.

Below is an example schematic followed by an oscilloscope trace showing the comparator in action.

Good luck with your project!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjIf5q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*"logic chips are always hard ON or OFF"* - This isn't exactly true. They do a good job forcing inputs to either logic 0 or 1, but if you have a slow, sloppy input transition, than you'll get a somewhat slow output transition as well. The transfer of an inverter looks kind of like an S curve:

[image]

I doubt that this will give your downstream circuit any problems, but it might be good to be aware of it. If fast transition is really important to you, then study the datasheets of the particular inverters you're looking at to get an idea of the sharpness of the transfer curve.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention a few important factors:

- what is the current (and less important, the voltage) you want to switch, and is your load resistive or inductive?
- what is the gate voltage your FET needs to switch fully on, and does that match the voltage your 555 runs on?
- at what frequency do you want to switch

A small current (let's say 100 mA) can often be switched by a FET directly from a 555 output. Larger currents can often be switched if the frequency is low.

For really large loads there are 'mosfet driver' chips that are specially designed to drive mosfets gates very quickly. Such chips can handle a current of 1 A or more for the short time needed to quickly charge or discharge a MOSFET gate.

IMO a gate (in the sense of a HC or HCT chip) offers little advantage over a 555 output.